# Running Armadilo in fortran

Tags: c++, fortran, gfortran

Is there any way of running scientific c++ libraries like armadilo in fortran? I googled but found no positive result.
For my works, it would be helpful to use armadilo syntaxes, short and easy to use but as a programming language, I have exposure to fortran only.

Comment: A book like modern fortran has a section in the back on mixed language.
I would start with a small example, and strings and painters are often where I spent the most time.
Generally you need to use ISO_C_BINDING on the fortran side as we'll a sub Pass by value.
But I have link with c and go.
And you may need the interface spec in the fortran side to mirror a .h file.

Comment: Much of 'armadillo syntax' can be done with standard F90+ array syntax, no? Or can you provide some concrete example what you're asking for?

Comment: For typical array operations (like whole-array / array section / sum / exp / etc), I believe the array syntax of Fortran >=90 is probably even more convenient than Armadillo, but I think the latter is appealing for Matlab-like features / wrappers like linear algebra and stats, e.g. http://arma.sourceforge.net/ http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html (Btw I guess https://github.com/fortran-lang/stdlib useful for this purpose in future...)

Answer (score 2):

Armadillo is based on templates. You cannot use C++ templates, or any other templates, in Fortran. A very good survey on using modern programming techniques and modern libraries in Fortran and C++ is in the book *Scientific Software Design: The Object-Oriented Way* by Rouson, Xia and Xu. They mention the problems of interoperability of such libraries.

You can use the algorithms implemented in the templated libraries even in Fortran, but you have to write some interfacing code and you lose the flexibility of templates. Basically, you need to instantiate the templates in C++ and you have to create proxy objects in Fortran.